# Responsive on mobile, but not on desktop

Tags: css, responsive-design, frontend

I have this issue with a site I need to modify. It's a site built with Bootstrap.

Something's going on with its breakpoints. On mobile Chrome on a 1080p screen it displays just fine and the breakpoints in the CSS seem to be correct. However, when I resize the browser window on a desktop to view it like on mobile, the whole page layout just breaks.

What could be the cause?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Inbuilt browser mobile screen emulators normally recommend refreshing the page after applying a new set of rules. Please try performing a hard refresh of the page after setting new viewport dimensions.